# Magento - AWS load balancing

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to host my magento store in the aws, through reading documentation and doing research i am like almost done with the architecture :
3 EC2 instances with DB MySql.
1 ELB

I have registered all 3 instances with the elb and if the hit the DNS(A record) of elb its even distributing to all three instances, but the problem i am facing is as soon as the load balancer lands me to any particular ec2 instance the url address changes to the ip address of that particular ec2 instance which actually should not happen and i don't want it to happen.

Please guys help me out with this.

Comment: what protocol did you set for your elb forward rules?

Comment: http protocol port 80

Comment: I suspect your magento application (either web server layer, or in php code) is redirecting you when landing on a VM. I don't think this is an ELB issue. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: or maybe you have to configure Magento to specify the host as the A record of the elb

Comment: check if httpx forwarded for is to be used for any application/module in magento.

Comment: In my magento db table: core_config_data the baseurl and secureurl value is set to the ip address of the respective ec2 instances

Comment: set this to the elb A record

Comment: Careful. There is more than 1 A record for an ELB, and they change. You should never refer to the ELB A record for this reason.

Comment: no the A record does not change for the ELB. The IPs behind the record change. So you should always use the A record of the ELB, or any route53 alias that you recorded

Comment: yes, so magento would keep redirect the clients to the elb, not to the instances directly. Also you can create aliases in route53  to get more friendly name if you wish and own a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url settings in magento to the ELB DNS name (or to any alias you recorded to this DNS name). your instances are redirecting you to these urls after the ELB, which by default seems to be the dns name of the instance, and they should redirect to the ELB instead.

One good point from Rodrigo M also: for security purposes, your instances should only communicate to the ELB subnet.

Comment: see this topic, which seems to describe this pretty well https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_configure_magento_to_work_with_a_new_domain/

Comment: Thank you very much tom your suggestion helped a lot, thank you. Actually i changed the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url settings as per your suggestion and enabled stickiness it started working for me.